# Accessing sub lists from netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to access the json data in the format liike below...

```
{"subscriptions":
    "recmachcustrecord2": [{
    "custrecord_acceptable_min_shelf_life": "60",
    "custrecord_item": {
        "internalid": "399",
        "name": "ABS2002-PACK"
    }
}, {
    "custrecord_acceptable_min_shelf_life": "60",
    "custrecord_item": {
        "internalid": "400",
        "name": "ABS2003-PACK"
    }
}]
}
```

I have written like
var subrec = salesRepRec.getSublistSubrecord({
 sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord2',
 fieldId: 'custrecord_item',
 line: 0
 });

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"FIELD_1_IS_NOT_A_SUBRECORD_FIELD","message":"Field custrecord_item is not a subrecord field.","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","onAfterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/cus.js:23)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"FIELD_1_IS_NOT_A_SUBRECORD_FIELD","details":"Field custrecord_item is not a subrecord field.","userEvent":"aftersubmit","stackTrace":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","onAfterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/cus.js:23)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

mainly i want access the  `"internalid": "400",
            "name": "ABS2003-PACK"` these fields.

how can i access the using the suite script 2.0

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK NetSuite does not allows creating a custom sublist subrecord. Although in you case, you only need to fetch *internalid* and *itemid* from the subrecord which can be achieved as below

```
{
    custrecord_item: { 
       internalId: salesRepRec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord2', fieldId: 'custrecord_item', line: 0 }),
       name: salesRepRec.getSublistText({ sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord2', fieldId: 'custrecord_item', line: 0 })
    }
}
```